# Error: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, webpack

I'm getting this weird error when I'm trying to do a "npm run dev". First, I cloned a repo, then changed into that project folder where I did a "npm install".

After it was done, I tried the "npm run dev", but it gave me a long error:

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration[0].mode should be one of these:
   "development" | "production" | "none"
   -> Enable production optimizations or development hints.
 - configuration[1].mode should be one of these:
   "development" | "production" | "none"
   -> Enable production optimizations or development hints.

My webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

const serverConfig = {
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
    entry: './src/server/server.ts',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    configFile: 'tsconfig.server.json'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'server.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    target: 'node',
    node: {
        __dirname: false
    },
    externals: [nodeExternals()]
};

const clientConfig = {
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
    entry: './src/client/index.tsx',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            options: {
                configFile: 'tsconfig.client.json'
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader',
                'sass-loader',
            ]
        }
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.css', '.scss']
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'app.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js')
    }
};

module.exports = [serverConfig, clientConfig];
```

Comment: Can you share your package.json scripts section?

Comment: "scripts": {
    "watch:build": "npx webpack -w",
    "watch:server": "nodemon dist/server.js",
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel watch:*",
    "start": "node dist/server.js"
  },